# Creating a good training set for one-class detection

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am training a one-class (hands) object detector on the egohands data set. My problem is that it detects way too many things as hands. It feels like it is detecting everything that is skin-colored as a hand.

I assume the most likely explanation for this is that my training set is poor, as every single image of the set contains hands, and also almost no other skin-toned elements are on the images. I guess it is necessary to also present the network images that are *not* what you try to detect?

I just want to verify I am right with my assumptions, before investing lots of time into creating a better training set. Therefore I am very grateful for every hint want I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Object detection preprocessing is critical step, take extra caution guards as detection networks are sensitive to geometrical transformations.

Some proven data augmentation methods include:

1.Random geometry transformation for random cropping (with constraints),

2.Random expansion,

3.Random horizontal flip

4.Random resize (with random interpolation).

5.Random color jittering for brightness, hue, saturation, and contrast

Comment: Hi TFer, thanks for your answer! Are you saying these are things that should be added to the datasets, or that should be avoided?
When using transfer learning using the object detection api, which I am trying to do, is it also necessary to add images of things I do not want to detect? Say, I want to train to detect hands, do I also add images of horses. Or even better, things that look more closely like hands, but are not?